# How to set default ID equal ID of item (VueJS,VueX,VueComponent,VueRouter)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vue-router

I got stuck with this request (in Video)
https://www.loom.com/share/d43520400b9e470397204eb0604a6a11 (this is test site)
Brief request: When you login dashboard (I skipped this step), the company's ID default is newest (latest created). In video is 1246(sweltering swim), when you choose(change) company the Button have change UI and the url change accord selected company's ID. Then when you choose option in Navbar(Sidebar) it's got selected company's ID too.

Now I just did to this part, choose company and get selected ID. I dont know how to set default ID when login, you can watch video to know my issue
https://www.loom.com/share/53bf9663987e4dfc87b564ed65ad6e1e (this is my clone from test site). I just can get ID when click choose but when I jump to dashboard, all sidebar not working

My appbar

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-app-bar
      color="#f5f5f5"
      dense
      dark
      style="height: 70px; padding: 10px 0px; box-shadow: none"
    >
      <v-btn color="#f5f5f5" id="hide-menu">
        <v-icon color="#1F2939">{{ icons.mdiMenu }}</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
      <v-menu offset-y>
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
          <v-btn
            color="#f5f5f5"
            dark
            v-bind="attrs"
            v-on="on"
            class="logo-company"
          >
            <v-btn color="rgb(242, 179, 52)" style="box-shadow: none">
              <h4 style="color: white">C</h4>
            </v-btn>
            <span style="color: #616e7c; font-size: 15px" class="font-res"
              >{{ selectedCompany }}
            </span>
            <v-icon color="#616e7c">{{ icons.mdiChevronDown }}</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
        </template>
        <v-list>
          <v-list-item
            @click="selectCompany(company.id)"
            v-for="company in companies"
            :key="company.id"
          >
            <v-list-item-title>{{ company.name }}</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list>
      </v-menu>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-btn color="#f5f5f5" id="appear-option">
        <v-icon color="#1F2939">{{ icons.mdiDotsHorizontal }}</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
      <a href="" class="contact-us">Contact Us</a>
      <div class="mx-2"></div>
      <v-menu left bottom>
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
          <v-btn
            v-btn
            v-bind="attrs"
            v-on="on"
            color="#f5f5f5"
            id="hide-option"
          >
            <h5 style="color: #1f2933; font-size: 15px; font-weight: 400">
              {{ user.firstName }} {{ user.lastName }}
            </h5>
            <div class="px-1"></div>
            <v-icon color="#DDE2E9">{{ icons.mdiAccount }}</v-icon>
            <div class="px-1"></div>
            <v-icon color="#1F2939">{{ icons.mdiChevronDown }}</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
        </template>
        <v-list>
          <v-list-item
            v-for="list in listMenu"
            :key="list"
            link
            @click="$router.push({ path: list.route })"
          >
            <v-list-item-title>{{ list.name }}</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list>
      </v-menu>
      <v-btn @click="signout" id="hide-option" color="#f5f5f5"
        ><v-icon color="#f2b334">{{ icons.mdiLogoutVariant }}</v-icon></v-btn
      >
    </v-app-bar>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import {
  mdiAccount,
  mdiChevronDown,
  mdiLogoutVariant,
  mdiMenu,
  mdiDotsHorizontal,
} from "@mdi/js";
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";
export default {
  data: () => ({
    listMenu: [
      { name: "Profile", route: "/profile" },
      { name: "Event log", route: "/dashboard" },
    ],
    icons: {
      mdiAccount,
      mdiLogoutVariant,
      mdiMenu,
      mdiDotsHorizontal,
      mdiChevronDown,
    },
    items: [
      {
        text: "Dashboard",
        disabled: false,
        href: "breadcrumbs_dashboard",
      },
      {
        text: "Link 1",
        disabled: false,
        href: "breadcrumbs_link_1",
      },
      {
        text: "Link 2",
        disabled: true,
        href: "breadcrumbs_link_2",
      },
    ],
  }),
  methods: {
    selectCompany(companyId) {
      this.$store.dispatch("companies/selectCompany", companyId);
      this.$router.push({ path: `/companies/${companyId}/setting` });
    },
    signout() {
      this.$store
        .dispatch("signout/signoutAccount")
        .then(this.$route.push({ path: "/auth/signin" }));
    },
    getCompanies() {
      this.$store.dispatch("companies/getCompanies");
    },
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      companies: "companies/allCompanies",
      selectedCompany: "companies/selectedCompany",
      user: "profile/userNameGetter",
    }),
  },
};
</script>
```

My navbar (sidebar)

```
 <template>
      <v-navigation-drawer
        color="rgb(79,37,102)"
        floating
        persistent
        mobile-breakpoint="991"
        width="210"
        absolute
      >
        <v-img :src="image" height="100%">
          <v-layout class="fill-height" tag="v-list" column>
            <v-btn
              style="margin: 17px auto"
              dark
              color="rgb(242, 179, 52)"
              class="d-flex justify-center"
              to="/companies"
            >
              <h5 style="color: white; font-size: 20px">C</h5>
            </v-btn>
            <v-divider />
            <div class="mt-16"></div>
            <v-btn color="rgb(242, 179, 52)" fab dark small class="move-btn">
              <v-icon>mdi-chevron-left</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
            <router-link
              v-for="(link, i) in links"
              :key="i"
              :to="link.to"
              class="list-item"
              style="color: #c8cde2; font-weight: 300; font-size: 18px"
            >
              <v-list-title class="hover-lt">
                <v-list-title-action>
                  <v-icon
                    style="color: #c8cde2; font-size: 35px; padding-right: 12px"
                    >{{ link.icon }}</v-icon
                  >
                </v-list-title-action>
                <v-list-title-title v-text="link.text" />
              </v-list-title>
            </router-link>
          </v-layout>
        </v-img>
      </v-navigation-drawer>
    </template>
    <script>
    export default {
      data: () => ({
        links: [
          {
            to: `dashboard`,
            icon: "mdi-view-dashboard",
            text: "Dashboard",
          },
          {
            to: `sales`,
            icon: "mdi-currency-usd",
            text: "Sales",
          },
          {
            to: `contacts`,
            icon: "mdi-domain",
            text: "Contacts",
          },
          {
            to: `products`,
            icon: "mdi-cube-outline",
            text: "Products",
          },
          {
            to: `fees`,
            icon: "mdi-calculator-variant-outline",
            text: "Fees",
          },
          {
            to: `employees`,
            icon: "mdi-account-supervisor",
            text: "Employees",
          },
          {
            to: `setting`,
            icon: "mdi-cog",
            text: "Company setting",
          },
        ],
      }),
      computed: {
        id() {
          return this.$store.state.companies.routeId;
        },
      },
    };
    </script>
```

I used to try set link is

```
{
            to: `this.$route.params.${companyId}/fees`,
            icon: "mdi-calculator-variant-outline",
            text: "Fees",
          },
```

But $route is undefined.

What I can do ... If you wanna info about code to know my issue, tell me.

Comment: You sets `$route.params` as string, not as js code:
`this.$route.params.${companyId}/fees` -> `${this.$route.params.companyId}/fees`

Comment: tks for your response but it's not working. the Error is :Error in data(): "TypeError: Cannot read property '$route' of undefined"